# jQuery attr replace on aspx

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net

I work with php/mysql and of course BUT one guy called me yesterday with a problem that a can't solve

he have this code:

```
<a href='#'  class="fancybox-effects-d classelink">
    <telerik:RadBinaryImage 
    runat="server"
    Style="width: 100%; height: auto;" 
    ID='RadBinaryImage' 
    DataValue='<%#Eval("IMAGEM")%>'
    AutoAdjustImageControlSize="false"
    ToolTip='<%#Eval("TITULO")%>'
    AlternateImage='<%#Eval("IMAGEM") %>'
    ResizeMode="crop" modal="true" />
</a>
```

he want to replace de `href="#"` with the src from the image
i don't have any idea of how to do that, i tried jquery but i failed

Comment: I would suggest you to add an `id` attribute and get it with `document.getElementById('your_id').setAttribute("href", "anything you want")`.

Comment: if you can alter the html, your best option would really be dontvote's suggestion. if you cannot however, then we need more information about those anchors, how many of them your guy has on the page, are they all the same? does he need to replace the href in all of them? if yes, do the links need to be different or same link for all anchors ?

Comment: he have like a foreach with images that comes from the db and he want to put the image as a link to itself
sorry for my english

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think jQuery is a good way to do this, you wouldn't need to really modify the html or asp at all:

```
$(function() {
    $('a.fancybox-effects-d.classelink').each(function(index, element) {
        $(this).attr('href', $(this).find('img').attr('src'));
    });
});
```

If there are lots of 'fancybox-effects-d' and 'classelink' classed elements just add a special class for all of the a tags in question-- adding an ID can definitely work too if you did it in the html markup